# Problem creating and populating table oracle php ORA-00933 ORA-00922 ORA-00928

Tags: php, oracle, sqlplus

I've been using an Oracle database in a website but I've been getting errors when dropping, creating or inserting into tables.

Dropping gives

> Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Creating gives

> Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Inserting gives

> Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

Edit:(Fixed inserting)

```
<?php
putenv("ORACLE_SID=teaching");
if ($Connection = oci_connect("username", "password")){
    $sql = "DROP table BRANCH;";
    $Statement = oci_parse($Connection, $sql);
    oci_execute($Statement);

//drop rest of tables

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE Branch
        (Branch#    Number,
        PRIMARY KEY(Branch#));";
    $Statement = oci_parse($Connection, $sql);
    oci_execute($Statement);

//create rest of tables

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Branch VALUES (12);";
    $Statement = oci_parse($Connection, $sql);
    oci_execute($Statement);

//insert rest of data
   oci_close($Connection);
}else{
   var_dump(oci_error($Connection));
}
?>
```

Comment: You missed `values`. It should be `insert into Branch values (12);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>*(@PonderStibbon already answered in the comment, I'm putting it into an answer for posteriry - thus Community Wiki.)*</sub>

In the last statement, where your are inserting values into the table, your syntax for the `INSERT` command is incorrect.  The correct syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO Branch VALUES (12)
```